# Why does SQL Server say this function is nondeterministic?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, non-deterministic

Execute this function in T-SQL:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Parse_URI_For_Scheme](
         @URI nvarchar(4000))
RETURNS nvarchar(250)
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN

   DECLARE @temp_string varchar(4000)
   DECLARE @return_string nvarchar(250)
   DECLARE @pos int

   SET @pos = CHARINDEX('://', @URI);
   --select @pos
   IF @pos > 0
      BEGIN
         SET @temp_string = SUBSTRING(@URI, 0, @pos);

         -- SET @pos = CHARINDEX('/', @temp_string)

         IF @pos > 0
            BEGIN
               SET @temp_string = LEFT(@temp_string, @pos - 1);

               SET @pos = CHARINDEX('@', @temp_string);

               IF @pos > 0
                  SET @return_string = SUBSTRING(@temp_string, @pos + 1, 250);
               ELSE
                  SET @return_string = @temp_string;
            END
         ELSE
            SET @return_string = '';
      END
   ELSE
      SET @return_string = '';

   RETURN @return_string;

END;
```

Then execute this command which returns 0:

```
SELECT OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('[dbo].Parse_URI_For_Scheme'), 'IsDeterministic')
```

Can someone please tell me why this is not a deterministic function?

Comment: Just as an aside, why not just set return_string to empty string immediately after you declare it? You can remove some of your else's that do nothing but that, making it a bit easier to follow.

Comment: It returns 1 for me, which is as expected!

Comment: returns 1 for me too. which version of sql server?

Comment: You might be better suited turning this into an inline table valued function instead of a scalar function.

Comment: Same here, the function is deterministic... (returns `1`). Are you sure to check the correct database / version / schema? Are there transactions involved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the key points for SQL Server to mark a function as Deterministic is the `SchemaBinding` feature. For your function to be deterministic you need to define the function using `With SchemaBinding`.

In Your example if you remove the `With SchemaBinding`, the `ObjectProperty` function will return 0 for the `IsDeterministic` attribute, so by adding the `With SchemaBinding` the problem will be resolved for you

[@Paul has detailed explanation around this issue, here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/140382)

Answer (score 0):

Vahid's gave a great reply. I agree with everything he said and love the link to the Paul White comment which is excellent.

A couple things to note:

**1. The logic you're using is overly complex for what you are trying to do.**

I think you could get away with:

```
SUBSTRING(@URI, 1, ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('://', @URI)-1,0),''))
```

**2. If you must have a function for this task use an inline Table Valued Function (iTVF).**

This advice changed my career and what I've learned over the years is that there are two kinds of T-SQL functions: iTVFs and very slow functions (e.g. Scalar and multi-statement table valued functions). Here's more great reading from Paul White on this topic: [Understanding and Using APPLY (Part 1)](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/APPLY/69953/).

Let's turn your function into a high-performing, parallelism-enabled DETERMINISITC function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.parse_uri_for_scheme_itvf(@URI nvarchar(4000))
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS RETURN
SELECT newURI = SUBSTRING(@URI, 1, ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('://', @URI)-1,0),''));
```

and a performance test to demonstrate why scalar functions are not for people in a hurry.

**Sample Data**

```
SELECT string = cast(pr+'://'+samples.txt as nvarchar(4000))
INTO #strings
FROM (VALUES ('http'),('https'),('ftp')) pr(pr)
CROSS JOIN 
(
  SELECT replicate(newid(), abs(checksum(newid())%2)+1)
  FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) a(x),
       (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) b(x),
       (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) c(x),
       (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) d(x),
       (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) e(x)
) samples(txt);
```

**Perf Test**

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
PRINT 'Scalar'+char(10)+replicate('-',60);
GO
DECLARE @st datetime = getdate(), @txt nvarchar(4000);
SELECT @txt = dbo.Parse_URI_For_Scheme(t.string)
FROM #strings t;
PRINT datediff(ms,@st,getdate())
GO 3

PRINT 'iTVF'+char(10)+replicate('-',60);
GO
DECLARE @st datetime = getdate(), @txt nvarchar(4000);
SELECT @txt = itvf.newURI
FROM #strings t
CROSS APPLY dbo.parse_uri_for_scheme_itvf(t.string) itvf;
PRINT datediff(ms,@st,getdate())
GO 3
```

**Results**

```
Scalar
------------------------------------------------------------
Beginning execution loop
1423
1380
1360
Batch execution completed 3 times.

iTVF
------------------------------------------------------------
Beginning execution loop
423
427
437
Batch execution completed 3 times.
```

I knew the iTVF would be 3-4 times faster before I prepared the test.